# Can the Delphi 2010 IDE add relative search paths to a project

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

We have recently upgraded from Delphi 2009 to 2010.

One of the things in 2009 that suited us well was when you added a search path to a project (via Project -> Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Search Path) and used the browse dialog, the IDE would add in the relative path.

In 2010 this seems to have changed to absolute paths.  Is there any way to change this behaviour back to relative paths?

I know you can still type the relative path in but it was handy using the dialog to browse.

Comment: It really automatically did Relative Paths in D2009, I tried in D2007 and D2010 and its always absolute.   I still can type relative paths.

Comment: I've pressed F6 key to look for this but there's no such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Delphi2010**, I haven't seen any option to switch between relative and absolute path. You must modify it by hand after the execution of the dialog box.

To be honest, I was not aware that Delphi2009 was working with Relative path for this topic.